# save the current data of the arraylist when closing the app and retrieve it upon returning android

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

i'm new to android, and i have arraylist that stores data from users input and i want to save that data when the user closes the app and retrieve it when the user opens the app again
here is my code

```
String getInput= inputText.getText().toString();
            if(addArray.contains(getInput) || getInput.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item Already Added or Cannot Be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                addArray.add(getInput);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,addArray);

                show = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.arrayList);
                show.setAdapter(adapter);

                ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtInput)).setText(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PreferenceManager;

Here is an example saving the password and getting it when the app opened

```
 public class SavedPreference 
{
static final String PREF_USER_NAME = "username";
static final String PREF_PASS = "password";

static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ct)
{
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ct);
}

public static void setUserName(Context ctx, String userName) 
{
    Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
    editor.putString(PREF_USER_NAME, userName);
    editor.commit();
}

public static void eraseSavedPreference(Context ctx)
{
    Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getUserName(Context ctx)
{
    return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_USER_NAME, "");
}
```

}

When you want to check if a certain string is saved by the time the app executed

---

```
 if(SavedPreference.getUserName(this).length() == 0)
    {
        //string not found
    }else
    {
        //string found
    }
```